# how to duplicate my sql results?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to get multiple results from one line in table based on a number of that table.

```
ID | count
A  | 12
B  | 138
```

So I want the output of the query to be 12 times A (no matter if with a counter or not) and 138 times B.
I have seen a solution by adding a count table on the DB, but I can't do that.

Comment: Can you show an example of the result ?

Comment: Is there any code that you have tried?

Comment: I had tried with some dual tricks, but the answer of Mt() work perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a correlated hierarchical query:

```sql
SELECT t.id, r.COLUMN_VALUE, t.cnt
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS JOIN
       TABLE(
         CAST(
           MULTISET(
             SELECT LEVEL
             FROM   DUAL
             CONNECT BY LEVEL <= t.cnt
           )
           AS SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST
         )
       ) r;
```

or a recursive sub-query factoring clause:

```sql
WITH row_generator ( id, lvl, cnt ) AS (
  SELECT id, 1, cnt
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT id, lvl + 1, cnt
  FROM   row_generator
  WHERE  lvl < cnt
)
SELECT *
FROM   row_generator
ORDER BY id, lvl
```

So for the test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( ID, cnt ) AS
SELECT 'A',  12 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 138 FROM DUAL
```

Both these solutions would output:

> ```
> ID | COLUMN_VALUE | CNT
> :- | -----------: | --:
> A  |            1 |  12
> A  |            2 |  12
> A  |            3 |  12
>           ...
> A  |           10 |  12
> A  |           11 |  12
> A  |           12 |  12
> B  |            1 | 138
> B  |            2 | 138
> B  |            3 | 138
> B  |            4 | 138
>           ...
> B  |          136 | 138
> B  |          137 | 138
> B  |          138 | 138
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=bf6725aae60a53a465cb3a0912456471)*

Comment: works all great, thx, but i have to put r.* couse the table dont give columna name.

Comment: The name of the generated column is `COLUMN_VALUE` but you can alias it to anything you want.